# How can I tell if a user opened my iOS app from the home screen icon (without 3D touch)?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

How can I tell if a user used the icon from the home screen? (as opposed to from a notification, for example)

`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` signals the initial launch, but has no way to indicate whether it was opened from the home screen icon or opened from the app switcher after being terminated by the OS.

`application(_:performActionFor:completionHandler:)` is only for 3D touch actions.

`applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)` is better than `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)` since it doesn't get called after opening the UI Notification Center, but still can be called for other reasons.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to know this?

Comment: I want to show an animation when a user opens the app, but only if they open from the home screen button

Comment: But why? Opening is opening. If the app is terminated, _we are launching_. There is no distinction to be drawn.

Comment: There are multiple ways to enter an app, and it informs as to the user's mindset, which is useful for certain kinds of product design.

Comment: There IS a distinction between opening and launching. Launch is only called for the initial open. But an open could be from the initial launch, from a notification, from the app switcher, from unlocking after lock, etc.